# php populate option box from database table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am writing code to register a new project via a html form. I want to be able to click a dropdown box which pulls the values from a table on the database.

At the moment a dropdown box displays but with no values.

PLEASE NOTE: I am a learning the basics so apologies if this is a simple question/answer scenario.

My code is below, any help is appreciated, I connect to the database via a php include script. The table is called 'customers' and the item I want to list is 'name';-

```
    <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT customers FROM name"); 
 echo "<select name='client'>"; 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 { 
    echo "<option value = '".$row[name]."'>".$row[name]."</option>"; 
 }
 echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: thanks Fred, I thought I'd tried this combination!

Comment: You're welcome Dan, I deleted my comment and decided to post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"The table is called `'customers'` and the item I want to list is `'name'`;"* -

Do `SELECT name FROM customers` instead of `SELECT customers FROM name`

- Using `mysql_error()` to `mysql_query()`
  would have shown you the error that the table `name` does not exist.

*Plus,*
`[name]` are missing quotes inside them => `['name']` which are being treated as [**constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

in

```
echo "<option value = '".$row[name]."'>".$row[name]."</option>";
```

as caught and kudos to `devdesign`

```
echo "<option value = '".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
```

However, you are using a deprecated MySQL library. If you are still not getting results, then this could mean that you need to use (and should use) `mysqli_` or PDO instead.

Here are a few links on the subject:

- [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
- [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be. Also note the single quotes within $row['name']. You missed that.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM customers"); 
 echo "<select name='client'>"; 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 { 
    echo "<option value = '".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>"; 
 }
 echo "</select>";
?>
```